# Updating notification causes loop with BroadCast Reciever

Tags: android, notifications

I have a notification, and I am trying to update the notification but I am having trouble with my BroadCast receiver.

I am calling my method that updates the notification here, in my broadcast receiver:

```
        this.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                nextSongorPrevious(songPathsAll, "next", true);

                updateNotification("");

            }
        }, new IntentFilter("Next"));
```

That broadcast receiver with the intent Next is hooked up to a button like this:

```
 PendingIntent next = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1,
                new Intent("Next"), 0);
        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.nNext, next);
```

And this is the method I am calling to update my Notification:

```
  public void updateNotification(String what) {

    Notification notification = getMyActivityNotification(what);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notif_id, notification);
}
```

The problem I am having is when I call the method to update my notification, the "Next" broadcast receiver is called over and over again, and I don't know why.

Here's the full notification:

```
private Notification getMyActivityNotification(String text){
    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects
    // this notification

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, new Intent(this, Main_activity.class), 0);

    Notification.Builder mainBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this);



    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(
            context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);


    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.nSongArtist,
            ArtistNames.get(position2));

    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.nSongTitle,
            SongName());





    if(text == "play"){

        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.nPlay,
                R.drawable.pause_black);


    }

    if(text == "pause"){

        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.nPlay,
                R.drawable.play_black);



    }

    if(text == "pause"){

        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.nPlay,
                R.drawable.play_black);


    }


        this.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                nextSongorPrevious(songPathsAll, "next", true);

                Intent i = new Intent("fsNext");
                sendBroadcast(i);

                updateNotification("");


            }
        }, new IntentFilter("Next"));



        PendingIntent next = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1,
                new Intent("Next"), 0);

        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.nNext, next);



    return mainBuilder
                .setContent(contentView)

            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play_white)

            .setContentTitle(SongName())
            .setContentText(ArtistNames.get(position2))
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent).getNotification();



}
```

If someone could help me out, that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I found that when I send a Broadcast, the Receiver recieves it multiple times. Seems like the Broadcasts are "echoing".

Comment: yeah it seems that way, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I was sending Broadcast from a Service to an Activity. I managed to get around the echo by setting and checking for boolean flags in both the Service and the Activity.